# Marshalling char** in a more human way

Tags: c#, c++, string, marshalling

I have the following interface method declaration in C#:

```
[ComVisible(true), ComImport, SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity,
Guid("A668B8F2-BA87-4F63-9D41-768F7DE9C50E"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ILAVAudioStatus
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetOutputDetails(out IntPtr pOutputFormat, out int pnChannels, out int pSampleRate, out uint pChannelMask);
}
```

pOutputformat is actually a char** in C++

I need to do a `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pOutputformat)` to get the actual string.

Is there some marshalling attribute that can convert pOutputformat directly to an out string instead of using an IntPtr?

This is what the C++ method does:

```
HRESULT CLAVAudio::GetOutputDetails(const char **pOutputFormat, int *pnChannels, int *pSampleRate, DWORD *pChannelMask)
{
  if(!m_pOutput || m_pOutput->IsConnected() == FALSE) {
    return E_UNEXPECTED;
  }
  if (m_avBSContext) {
    if (pOutputFormat) {
      *pOutputFormat = get_sample_format_desc(SampleFormat_Bitstream);
    }
    return S_FALSE;
  }
  if (pOutputFormat) {
    *pOutputFormat = get_sample_format_desc(m_OutputQueue.sfFormat);
  }
  if (pnChannels) {
    *pnChannels = m_OutputQueue.wChannels;
  }
  if (pSampleRate) {
    *pSampleRate = m_OutputQueue.dwSamplesPerSec;
  }
  if (pChannelMask) {
    *pChannelMask = m_OutputQueue.dwChannelMask;
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Depending on thow the method uses the parameter a `out StringBuilder` could work.

Comment: out stringBuilder crashes the app, while just stringBuilder gives back a stringBuilder filled with the pointer instead of the value (4 bytes of garbage).

Comment: Yes, that can happen. Marshalling output parameters is a bit annoying because it depends on the method handles it and whether it allocates memory or the calling function.

Comment: well the method in C++ does as what you would expect it puts the pointer to his internal string into the pOutputformat, then i read it with PtrToStringAnsi. I am just wondering if there is a way to declare the parameter as out string in some way, since it obviously doesnt work with "out string"

Comment: You cannot pinvoke a C++ instance method.  That it doesn't crash when it accesses the m_Output and m_avBSContext members was blind luck.  That will not repeat well.

Comment: So why does the C++ method use a char** as a parameter?  From the looks of it, a char* is all that is required.  Then you just copy the info from the get_sample_format_desc to the pointed-to buffer.  I see no reason on the surface for a char** in your case.

Comment: The C++ code is not mine, I just want the interop in a more human way: ie getting a string directly without needing PtrToStringAnsi

Comment: Hans I am not doing pInvoke, I am doing an IUnknown interface in C# for the C++ class. I'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Isn't `HRESULT` better mapped to `uint`?

Comment: You are right, ULONG in c++ should mean uint. My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pOutputformat)
```

is the best that you can do. There's no avoiding that. If you try to marshal as `out string OutputFormat` then the marshaller will call `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer returned by the native code. And that ends in tears.

The question remains as to who is responsible for deallocating the memory that `pOutputformat` points to? Only you can know the answer to that.

One wonders why the designer of this COM interface chose to use C strings rather than the COM `BSTR`.

Comment: I know it sucks exactly for the lack of BSTR, but I can't do much about it :(

Anyway from the look at the c++ code it seems I'm responsible to free whatever "*pOutputFormat = get_sample_format_desc()" puts into my pointer.

Right?

Comment: @MarinoŠimić You can only free it if you know which heap it was allocated from, or the library supplies you with a deallocator. Sometimes libraries return pointers to statically allocated strings in which case no deallocation is needed. There's no way for any of us to know those specifics.

Comment: I found the get_sample_format_desc:

const char *get_sample_format_desc(LAVAudioSampleFormat sfFormat)
{
  return sample_format_strings[sfFormat];
}

Seems no deallocation is needed since it just returns a string from 

static const char *sample_format_strings[] = {
  "16bit Integer",
  "24bit Integer",
  "32bit Integer",
  "8bit Integer",
  "32bit Float",
  "Bitstreaming"
};

Comment: Then you are good to go. `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` is essential for you.

Comment: I'm accepting you answer and thanks for the teaching class today. Always good to learn something, especially since i'm not so good at c++ and this kinds of interop.